# How to run VSCode from Window Comand Script

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-arguments

I would like to run VSCode from Windows Command Script with options of extensions-dir and user-data-dir.
It is ok on Windows Command Prompt.
But it is failed on Windows Command Scripts.
I tried many ways but all failed.
These is codes I'm trying:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set VSCODE_DEV=
set ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1
set configpath=%~dp0..\extensions
set extensionpath=%~dp0..\settings
set exepath=%~dp0..\Code.exe
::"%~dp0..\Code.exe" "--extensions-dir=\"D:\Windows\Programs\VSCode\extensions\""
::"%~dp0..\Code.exe" "--user-data-dir=D:\Windows\Programs\VSCode\settings" %*
::"%~dp0..\Code.exe --extensions-dir=D:\Windows\Programs\VSCode\extensions --user-data-dir=D:\Windows\Programs\VSCode\settings" %*
start "" "" "%~dp0..\Code.exe" "--help" "--version" "%~dp0..\resources\app\out\cli.js" %*
::start /d %exepath% "--list-extensions"
::start /WAIT /B "D:\Windows\Programs\VSCode\Code.exe"
endlocal
```

Could someone tell me how to fix it?

Thank you all with kind regards!

Comment: Just specify `code .`
it will start VS Code on the same path you script is in.

Comment: Yes sir. But I would want to config its custom extension path.
If there isn't extension path, there aren't any extensions to use.